# Is there a quick way to invert a node selection in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, editing

is there any way to invert a node selection in QGIS?

For example, I want to extract a small section of a long line - if I select the nodes I want to keep, is there any way to invert that selection so I can delete the unwanted nodes? The only way I can do it in v1.8 is to zoom all the way out, select all the nodes, zoom back in and deselect the ones I want to keep, then hit delete...which is a bit slow going...

Just wondered if there's a quicker way with a tool or keyboard shortcut?

Comment: I think your existing workflow is the one...

Answer (score 18):

The feature you seek is **Invert Feature Selection** accessible by the toolbar:

[image]

or via the menus, **Edit > Select > Invert Feature Selection**

Answer (score 6):

The fastest way I think would be to manually select the nodes you want to keep, open the attribute table and then use the keyboard shortcut for **Invert Selection** function ( CTRL + S ).

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way i know is to select all nodes per hand (maybe with the lasso or a rectangle).

Then you open the attribute-table and click on the following button
[image] 
This will switch your current selection to all previously unselected nodes.