# QGIS Expression with multiple IS NOT filters

Tags: qgis, select-by-expression

I would like to select features using an expression. I have one field with +-100  different values. I would like to select all values except for two. Something like this:
"FIELD" is NOT ( 'Value1',  'Value2' ), which would then select values 3 up to 98. However, this is all string text, not numbers 1 up to 100.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Im not an expert, but something like "FIELD IS NOT value1 AND FIELD IS NOT value2" wouldn't work?

Comment: that actually worked, thanks! Stupid i didn't think about it!

Comment: Another possibility is to select those you don't want: `FIELD = value1 or FIELD = value2`. When selected, click the icon for invert selection, see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/239184/88814

Comment: Ohh that is a nice one. I never noticed that icon before!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
"Field" not in ('Value 1', 'Value 2')
```

This should work for you.

Comment: Thanks that also works!